# Two way sync a single folder between two Macs via local network

Tags: itunes, network, data-synchronization

I've got two Macbooks and would like to two-way sync the ~/Music folder (200 GB).

**Is there reliable GUI tool that can do that automatically in the background when both computers are connected to the same network?**

*Why I need to do this:*

It contains my iTunes collection. On my "daily" Macbook I manage the files and sort the library. The "old" Macbook is my DJ notebook where I use the exact same collection. Sometimes I may change the tags so I need two-way sync.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a very similar situation a few years ago. I had a Mac mini and a MacBook. While the Mac mini contained all the tracks I wanted to use the MacBook like a giant iPod (sync star ratings, renamed songs, etc.).

---

### Solution: iTunes Match (music only)

1. Subscribe to [iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204439) on your main iTunes Library.
2. Wait for iTunes to upload/verify all unmatched songs in your library.
3. On you other Mac, turn on iTunes Match.
4. As soon as both libraries are updated, you can change a songs Metadata and it will sync over the internet.

Note:

It's a bit of a pain in the neck to wait for iTunes to upload all unmatched songs. But once that's achieved, it works like magic.

Comment: Wow, that is a nifty solution. What happens to meta data that is saved inside the files? e.g. the DJ softwares I use (Traktor and Rekordbox) save accurate BPM information, cue points etc directly inside the mp3s. I guess iTunes Match does not pick up these changes or does it?
Will iTunes Match also sync playlists? Those are the heart of the collection.

Comment: Yes, BPM metadata will be saved as well. The same is true for album artwork. Playlists: yes, most will work. Except for local playlists.

Comment: What do you mean with local playlists?

Comment: Smart playlists that depend on the existence of other playlists can not be synced using iTunes Match. All other normal and smart playlists will sync just fine.

Comment: @Hedge Does the solution above answer your question?